# Checking and comparing structure elements to a user input in C

Tags: c, string, search, structure

I am trying to make a function in C that **searches** in a database which consists of clients information, **compares** that to some user input, and eventually prints out good results based on a condition that relies on a Livenshtein distance percentage.

```
typedef struct Person_t
{
    char Name[32];
    char Email[64];
    char City[96];
    char Country[64];
} Person;
```

Here is the problem, the user is asked to enter each of the information represented by the structure members, BUT he can only enter what he wants, for example: Name: Emily , Email: (no user input aka left empty), City: (left empty) , Country: France.

And the goal here is to only compare these attributes (Emily, Country) to the respective ones in the database, because: As I said, the comparison algorithm is based on a condition related to the Livenshtein Distance, and if that condition doesn't pass say 50, it won't validate the search as a "good result" which might exclude good cases like, let's say:

**Name: Jack, Email: jack.jack@gmail.com , City: Birmingham, Country: United States**

This client exists in our "big" database (assuming we have a lot of Jacks and a lot of people from Birmingham), and smbd is making a search only knowing few things about Jack, so he enters:

**Name: Jackk , Email: (empty) , City: (empty) , Country: United Statesss**

(I am messing up the spelling intentionally to show how the LD can be useful, it will still score high in the percentage so don't worry about that)

The percentage condition using LD: **percentage = (1 - LD/max(string1, string2)) * 100** ,we're setting the cutoff on 50%.

The problem here is that if we compare **each and every** structure member with its corresponding one, one that pertains to what the user enters, we are **reducing** the likeliness of it scoring a good percentage, because comparing an empty string to an "existent" one will make it so that Livenshtein distance is big, and thus the percentage is *low* and that will take away a lot of good results.

It's important to note, that I don't want to use an **OR** . I don't know want that if he gets the "Jack" right, it will pass through (percentage = 100), that will not be efficient due to the existent of too many Jacks (we're talking about a big database), so I'm definitely working with an **AND**, to make sure all the user input is as close as possible to what he wants, and at the same time minimizing the number of results.

Bear in mind that beyond that, the post-search results are gonna be sorted based on the percentages, so dealing with the blank strings needs to be thoroughly done in accordance to that.

Comment: Couldn't you easily check for a blank string and either ignore it, or treat it as a perfect match?

Comment: That's my last card. I'm still confused about whether I need to check for a blank string before or within the comparison function..

Comment: Apart from that, I really want to somehow compare merely the components that the user entered, but I might have to add a switch case and ask the user what components does he know about the person basically, and re arrange the comparison after that, how realistic do you think that is ?

Comment: Write a comparison function that returns 0% (or some impossible value) when either of the strings to compare is empty. That way you'd automatically skip bad matches.

Comment: I think the question might be lacking in details for me to suggest specifics. But if the check is that for each field (i.e. AND of all), `percentage` >= 50, just treating blanks on the user side as 100 would work. If you're calculating the overall percentage over all fields, you can simply ignore these blanks in your calculation entirely.

Comment: @Hasturkun Exactly, that solves the problem, but the reason I didn't even think about that is that above all this, I want to sort the final searches out by let's say a mean value of all the percentages, and since the blank strings are treated as a 100, they will show up first and outclass one for instance that only made one slight misspelling of some component..I might try to mark the input that contains empty strings somehow, and print them out under some other condition..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of what I meant with my comment.

The `compare_field` function returns 1 if there was a valid match at all and populates the `percentage` out argument; it returns 0 if that field didn't matter.

The `compare_record` function calls that function 4 times, once for each field, and averages the percentages returned by the field comparison function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Person_t {
  char Name[32];
  char Email[64];
  char City[96];
  char Country[64];
} Person;

static Person database[] = {
    {.Name = "Emily",
     .Email = "emi@x.ly",
     .City = "Paris",
     .Country = "France"},
    {.Name = "Jack",
     .Email = "jack.jack@gmail.com",
     .City = "Birmingham",
     .Country = "United States"},
    {.Name = "Jank",
     .Email = "jankjank@gmail.com",
     .City = "London",
     .Country = "United Kingdom"},
};

static int compare_field(const char *record, const char *query,
                         float *percentage) {
  if (strlen(record) == 0 || strlen(query) == 0) {
    return 0; // Ignore this field in the search
  }
  // TODO: implement real levenshtein distance here
  int distance = 0;
  for (int i = 0;; i++) {
    if (record[i] == 0 || query[i] == 0)
      break;
    if (record[i] != query[i])
      distance++;
  }
  *percentage = (1.0f - distance / (float)strlen(record)) * 100.0f;
  return 1;
}

static float compare_record(const Person *record, const Person *query) {
  float total_match_percentage = 0, temp_percentage;
  int total_match_fields = 0;


  #define COMPARE_FIELD(field)  if (compare_field(record->field, query->field, &temp_percentage)) { total_match_percentage += temp_percentage; total_match_fields++; }

  COMPARE_FIELD(Name);
  COMPARE_FIELD(Email);
  COMPARE_FIELD(City);
  COMPARE_FIELD(Country);

  #undef COMPARE_FIELD

  return total_match_percentage / (float)total_match_fields;
}

int main() {
  int n_database = sizeof(database) / sizeof(Person);
  Person query = {.Name = "Jamk", .City = "Pondon", .Country = "United K"};
  for (int i = 0; i < n_database; i++) {
    float match = compare_record(&database[i], &query);
    printf("%s: %.2f\n", database[i].Name, match);
  }
}
```

With the `query` in the source, this prints out (since Emily still matches for `P`aris and I didn't implement a full Levenshtein distance algorithm)...

```
Emily: 13.33
Jack: 72.44
Jank: 86.11
```

Comment: I'd like to clarify that the record is never gonna be an empty string, only the query can be. And sorry to be fuzzy about that above, I did mention later in a comment, that I'm gonna need to sort out the post-search results depending on the score, and I don't want to totally discard the empty strings, and I equally don't wanna commit a high score to them just to pass the initial search because they might show up as good if not top results.

Comment: I'd add another struct á la `typedef SearchResult {Record *record; float percentage;}` you can sort on.

Comment: In other words, I would have done the checking (for the blank) almost like the way you did, but considering the fact that I need to sort it out later, I can't follow on this approach only when I know that I can deal with the data that contains blanks separately so it doesn't harm the results sorting.

Comment: Querying (=filtering) is one thing, sorting by relevance (computed during the query maybe) is another.

Comment: Thanks for the intervention and all the clarifications, one last thing, just curious how macroing the expression you referred to looks like (I never work with macro when it comes to if statements or long statements in general,

 `#define POGGERSIF (somefield)               \
if (compare_field(record->somefield, query->somefield, &temp_percentage)) ({    \
    total_match_percentage += temp_percentage;           \
    total_match_fields++;                \
  })`



is that correct ?

Comment: Something like that – I'd probably not bother with the newlines in a macro, since the compiler doesn't care and if your macro needs many newlines, it's too long in my opinion anyway. Edited the macro form into the answer.